# Make iOS app receive VoIP push notifications again

Tags: ios

Apple changed the way VoIP push notifications work. And apps not handling them  in the new way stop getting push notifications. The problem: Once this happens, how can I receive push notifications again with an updated application, without reinstalling the app?

(What I'm not asking is how to handle VoIP push notifications. That doesn't help because the app stopped receiving them, so it can't handle them either correctly or incorrectly).

Answer (score 1):

From what I've seen, the only way to receive VoIP notifications again is indeed reinstalling the app. If you can't do so, it seems that in around 24 hours you will be able to receive VoIP notifications again, without doing anything else than waiting.